# storing typedef constructor in class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, typedef

I am trying to figure out to store a typedef in my class, how would I do that? In the example posted I want to create a class which allows me to initiate a number of objects with different "Fct" parameters, like "one" or "slope", and or even change an object's "Fct f" with a set function:

```
typedef double Fct(double);

double one(double x) { return 1; }
double slope(double x) { return x / 2; }

struct myFct : Shape {
    myFct(Fct f)
        :f(f) {}; //"f" is not a nonstatic data member of base class of class "myFct"

private:
    Fct f;
};
```

Comment: Is `typedef double Fct(double);` meant to be `typedef double Fct;` or is it a forward function declaration? And what do you even mean by _store a typedef in my class_?

Comment: what is wrong with it? Please provide a [mcve], because as is i get errors not related to your question (`Shape` is not declared)

Comment: There is no such thing as "store a typedef". A typedef defines a new name for a type.

Comment: Maybe you want a function pointer (`Fct *f;`) which you can set with `f = one;` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out that quickly, using a pointer was the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `typedef` stands for a function type. That very `typedef` can be used to declare member functions. So your class has a *member function `f`* declaration. It accepts a double and returns a double.

I suspect what you want is a function pointer as a member *variable*. Do it explicitly:

```
struct myFct : Shape {
    myFct(Fct *f)
        :f(f) {}; //"f" is not a nonstatic data member of base class of class "myFct"

private:
    Fct *f;
};
```

You may consider yourself lucky, having stumbled on a somewhat obscure feature.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to ask the question as generic as possible, but as non-computer-science person sometimes even asking the right question is hard, you understood perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PhilippSiedler - You did the best thing a person not clear on the terms can do. And that is to show code. If a picture is worth a thousand words...